# saving temporary data on matlab gui

Tags: database, matlab, user-interface, save

I have made a GUI with Pushbutton and an Edit text. 
The first step is to enter initial data at the Edit text and then click on the Pushbutton.
Once the Pushbutton is clicked, it gathers some info from API and then it does some long calculations and shows the results in a table.

However, if I change my initial Edit text, i still want to use the API that was the same in the first click.

Is there a way to save the data and use it for the next Pushbutton clicks to save calculation time and not gather info from API everytime?

*I had like to save that data only as long as the code opened, just for the case i will need more calculations. I dont want to save the data with save function and then have MAT files on that folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach data to a specific GUI objects in different ways

**1. Using UserData**

The property `UserData` of an GUI object can store a variable of your choice (to store several variables just collect them in a struct, cell or array.
Use the object handle to [`get`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.get.html) or [`set`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.set.html?searchHighlight=UserData) the data. For example, to set/get the UserData of a edit text box with tag *edit1*

```
set(handles.edit1, 'UserData', 2)
get(handles.edit1, 'UserData')
ans = 
     2
```

Note that within a callback you can write `hObject` to get the current handle.

**2. Using application data**

A very simular method is to store data to a GUI object using [`setappdata`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) and thereby creating your own *key-value* map associated with that object/handle. The difference against the UserData method is that you can create several different key-value pairs (so the need to collect everything in a struct/cell/array isn't as imminent).

```
setappdata(handles.edit1, 'Foo', 1);
setappdata(handles.edit1, 'Bar', 3);
getappdata(handles.edit1)
ans =
      Foo: 1
      Bar: 3

getappdata(handles.edit1, 'Foo')
ans =
     1
```

**3. Using guidata**

Another variant is to assign a single varible (like for UserData) to *the main GUI figure* rather than to a specific handle. This is done by using `guidata`. No key/name is used to set the data.

```
guidata(anyHandleInGUI, myData)
```

The first input is a the main figure handle or any of its children.

```
guidata(handles.edit1, 5)
guidata(handles.edit1)
ans =
     5
```

Suppose your pushbutton has the tag *pushbutton1*. Since `guidata` locates the root parent (the figure handle) you can get the same data using its handle.

```
guidata(handles.pushbutton1)
ans =
     5
```

Comment: Is there a way to add data just into a variable and not into a GUI object? because i want it to work after clicking on an object but to save it as a global variable for next times i will need it.

Comment: @ben Perhaps you should look into [`persistent`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) variables. The value of theese are kept between calls. Use `isempty` to see if a variable are set, otherwise update it.
Another alternative are `global` variables but that should really be handled with care as it's easy to mess up